# Java: Start console parallel to GUI?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, console, swt

that might be some kind of a silly question for you guys, but anyways: Is it possible to start the Java-console (as it is shown in Eclipse) parallel to the actual SWT-GUI?
The console contains an awful lot of debugging-information and I want my testers to be able to see what's currently going on. Obviously, they're not gonna use Eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your program using `java` instead of `javaw`.

Another way is that you abstract your logging mechanism so that it uses console if one is attached to the process (when started with `java` or within Eclipse) or puts the messages in a separate window the user can open if they want.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application with the parameters:

-console -consoleLog